# Can you identify the manufacturer of this luxury vinyl plank?

Tags: flooring, vinyl

A piece of the flooring in our new home cracked and I’m having a hard time identifying exactly what brand it is in order to buy a replacement.

It is ~7 1/16” x 48” and 5mm thick with a pad. The most distinctive thing is the pad: A blue repeating cube pattern. Is this a clue to the manufacturer? Has anyone seen this before? [image: image depicting] I’ve been checking the backs of panels at some stores (Lowe’s, Home Depot and some local shops) and so far haven’t found this anywhere.

While I expect it will be hard to match the exact color by photo, here’s the front for what it’s worth: [image: image depicting front of plank] It’s visually quite similar to [Home Depot’s Lifeproof Dusk Cherry Luxury Vinyl Plank flooring](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lifeproof-Dusk-Cherry-6-MIL-x-8-7-in-W-x-48-in-L-Click-Lock-Waterproof-Luxury-Vinyl-Plank-Flooring-20-1-sqft-case-I06204L/306059551) as a reference point.

Appreciate any tips pointing in the right direction! Even good hunches are welcomed.

Comment: https://sango247.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/502-6-600x800.jpg

Comment: Have you taken that piece to your local flooring store(s) to see if they can help identify it? They may know where to find manufacturer marks on an actual piece and be able to ID it in moments...

Comment: The underlying pad may not even be from the same manufacturer. Taking the loose "board" to a store and trying to match it does sound like best bet.